# Change number of items per page using select box in UmbracoV7

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

I am using Umbraco7 and have created a view which uses pagination to display a list of items which works fine, but I would now like to implement functionality which will allow a user to select how many items to list per page via a select box

**View**

```
@{
    var SelectedPageSize = Request.Form["dropdownmenu"] ?? "1"; // Get the selectbox value or default to 1

    string[] DropDownValues = {"1", "2", "3", "4"}; // values for the selectbox dropdowns 

    int PAGE_SIZE = int.Parse(SelectedPageSize);  // parse those values

    var SearchResults = Umbraco.TypedSearch(Query, searchProvider: "SiteSearchSearcher", useWildCards: false).OrderBy(r => r.SortOrder);
    var TotalSearchResults = SearchResults.Count();
    var TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)TotalSearchResults / PAGE_SIZE);
    var CurrentPageNumber = 1;
    bool Parsed = int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["page"], out CurrentPageNumber);

    if (!Parsed || CurrentPageNumber < 1 || CurrentPageNumber > TotalPages)
    {
        CurrentPageNumber = 1;
    }

    <div class="containterdropdown">
        <div class="dropdown">
            Results Per Page
        </div>
        <select class="dropdownmenu" id="dropdownmenu" name="dropdownmenu">
        @foreach (var Item in DropDownValues)
        {
            <option value="@Item">@Item</option>
        }
        </select>
    </div>
};
```

I'd like to know how I could get the value from from the select option, following each change, into the variable named "SelectedPageSize". Am aware I will need some sort of javascript or ajax but I don't know anything about either of those  yet so I feel slightly lost. I have attempted to use the below snippet of js but am not sure what it's actually doing or how to get it to work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
('.containterdropdown').length) {
        var drpDnwBox = $('.containterdropdown select');
        drpDnwBox.on('change', function () { $(this).parents('form').submit(); });
```

Any help would be great... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got the select box working. It allows a user to select how many items they wish to be listed on a page.

**View**

```
var Query = Request.QueryString["q"] ?? ""; // The search term entered
var PageSize = Request.QueryString["PageSize"] ?? "20"; // The selected page size or default value
string[] DropDownValues = { "10", "20", "30", "40", "50" };

<div class="containterdropdown">
            <div class="dropdown">
                Results Per Page
            </div>
            <form method="get">
                <select class="dropdownmenu" id="dropdownmenu" name="dropdownmenu">
                    @foreach (var Item in DropDownValues)
                    {
                        if (PageSize == Item) // used to retain the selected value
                        {
                            <option value="@Item" selected>@Item</option>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <option value="@Item">@Item</option>
                        }
                    }
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var url = "@Model.Content.Url"; // get default url
        $('.dropdownmenu').on('change', function () {
            var SelectedValue = $('.dropdownmenu').val(); // on change assign the current selectbox value to the variable named "SelectedValue"
            window.location.href = url + '?q=@Query&PageSize=' + SelectedValue; // Reload the page with URL + the serch term + the page size
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've placed a get method on the form and then instead of using Reqeust.Form have used Request.QueryString.

The above JS will append the page size to the url and reload the page each time a new value is selected.

Answer (score 1):

By the look of your code, you are getting the page size by the first statement:

```
var SelectedPageSize = Request.Form["dropdownmenu"] ?? "1";
```

This means you are reading from the `Request.Form` collection.

If you google around, you will realize that `Request.Form` is items in the html  **form** element.

Having knowing the above statement, the first thing you will notice is that you are missing a form element ( at least from your code snippet, there is none), so add a form element to your drop down list, such as:

```
<div class="containterdropdown">
    <div class="dropdown">
        Results Per Page
    </div>
    <form id="myForm">
    <select class="dropdownmenu" id="dropdownmenu" name="dropdownmenu">
    @foreach (var Item in DropDownValues)
    {
        <option value="@Item">@Item</option>
    }
    </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

then we look at the jquery you provided:

I will simplify your jquery to something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#dropdownmenu').change(function(){
      $("#myForm").submit();
   });
})
```

The jquery snippet above means:

when drop down menu id dropdownmenu changes, please submit the form id myForm, 
and because your dropdownlist is in the form, it will be submitted, then when page load, your Request.Form["dropdownmenu"] will be able to pick up the value from the submission.

Make sure your page is referencing jquery library for the jquery snippet to work.

And the jquery snippet is not actually using ajax, it is just submitting the form when dropdownlist change.

If you are having trouble understanding jquery, I will suggest check out some of online courses such as this one from code school https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-jquery

hope above is clear enough

Comment: Hi Alan, I've tried what you suggested above but it still wasn't quite working, I have however got it working as expected using slightly different functionality. I'll post up my results soon. thanks for the help and explanation, it's cleared a few things up for me :)

Comment: I also wanted to ask, If I use request.form, should I be placing a Post method on the form?

Comment: glad to hear that you got it fixed. By default, form method use post, so you don't need to specify post.